# How can I subtract an object in dotnet core using the minus symbol? Similar to DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, syntax, operators

DateTimes in dotnet can be subtracted from each other using the symbol (-) and getting a span as a result. How can I replicate the behavior of DateTime to use the - symbol but for my own custom object

For example

```
Datetime a = DateTime.UtcNow();
Datetime b = DateTime.UtcNow();
Span c = b-a;
```

Thanks

Comment: Provide an implicit conversion from `TimeSpan` (which is what will result from your subtraction) to your `Span` type. That way, the TimeSpan that results from your `b-a` operation will be implicitly converted to a Span as the result of its assignment to a variable of type Span. I'm curious, why do you want to do this

Comment: Oh, I just realized that you have a separate type `Datetime` with no capital `T`. Create an `operator -` on that type that does what you want. By the way, you will hate yourself if you leave that type named as `Datetime`. Name it something obviously different from `System.DateTime`

Comment: The first thing you do are two assignments. These can't be overloaded; so you need to change to something like `Datetime a = new  Datetime (DateTime.UtcNow())`.. - Then you can indeed overload the addition and/or subtraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called operator overloading. Check the reference here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading

Of course, the implementation will totally depend on the logic you need to put beneath the operator. And of course, you are not bound to return the same type as your operands.

The example in your post is implemented like this:

```
public static TimeSpan operator -(DateTime d1, DateTime d2) {
  return new TimeSpan(d1.InternalTicks - d2.InternalTicks);
}
```

See here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,1503